# Seasonal adjusting with statsmodels: x13as not found in path

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am using Statsmodels to seasonally adjusted data.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.tsa as tsa

data = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\some\\Data.xlsx")
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=74, freq='Q')
data = data.set_index(rng)
target = data['target']
tsa.x13.x13_arima_analysis(target)
```

But I am getting this error:

> X13NotFoundError: x12a and x13as not found on path. Give the path, put
>   them on PATH, or set the **X12PATH** or **X13PATH** environmental
>   variable.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053770/arima-seasonal-prediction-with-python-x12a-and-x13as-not-found-on-path?answertab=active#tab-top) but the error persists. I have downloaded the programs from [here](https://www.census.gov/srd/www/winx13/winx13_down.html) and I have uncompressed the zip file in the **C drive**.